# PHP retrieve bitmask value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve a bitmask from a MySql DB table in PHP. I use the meekro db library to interact with the database.

Here is the code used to query the DB:

```
$query = DB::queryFirstRow($select, $tid);

$dm = $query['dayMask'];
var_dump($dm);
```

The row returned by the database contains a column named `dayMask`, which is defined as `BIT(7)` with the value `0110001`.

The above code prints `string(3) "127"` which makes no sense for me. The decimal representation of the mask is `49`, `127` corresponds to `1111111`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I retrieve a bitmask value from the DB in PHP?

Comment: PHP has no bitmask value type. Probably you should first of all research what exactly the database returns (e.g. by using the commandline client or the workbench gui) and then jump to conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was related to the SQL statement used to insert new values.

As I discovered, starting from the example provided by VolkerK, to insert bit value in MySQL I should use the following syntax (from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/bit-field-literals.html)):

```
mysql> INSERT INTO t SET b = b'1010';
```

Using this syntax my code works.

The strange thing is that inserting the value as a literal doesn't result in any error or warning from MySQL. Moreover, phpmyadmin displays the field correctly when inserted with the wrong syntax, while it displays the value incorrectly when inserted with the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

try with [bindec()](http://uk.php.net/bindec):

```
$dm = bindec($query['dayMask']);
```

Comment: i've already tried to convert the result but bindec prints out `int(1)`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the behaviour with

```
<?php
require 'meekrodb.2.0.class.php';
setup();
$select = 'SELECT * FROM tmpSO WHERE id=%s'; $tid = 1;
$query = DB::queryFirstRow($select, $tid);

$dm = $query['dayMask'];
var_dump($dm);



function setup() {
    DB::$user = 'localonly';
    DB::$password = 'localonly';
    DB::$dbName = 'test';
    DB::$host = 'localhost';
    DB::$port = '3306';
    DB::$encoding = 'utf8';
    DB::query('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpSO (
            id int auto_increment,
            dayMask BIT(7),
            primary key(id)
        )
    ');
    DB::query("INSERT INTO tmpSO SET dayMask = b'0110001'");
}
```

prints `string(2) "49"`

Comment: Thanks for your example. it points me to the right direction. I've never seen that (correct) syntax to insert bit in mysql.+1